# How to increment and decrement a specific item in ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

Here I am trying to increase a counter of a specific item/product on click of a plus button and decrease the counter by pressing the minus button which works absolutely fine. Now the real problem is that I want to increment/decrement for a specific item.

I tried many methods but I am still struggling.

my ts functions

```
    addQuantity(items){
            Object.keys(this.hideMe).forEach(h => {
              this.hideMe[items.ITEMID] = false;
            });
            this.hideMe[items.ITEMID] = true;
            this.item_qty+=1;
           }
     subQuantity(items){
        if(this.item_qty-1 < 1){
          this.item_qty = 1;
          console.log('item_1->' + this.item_qty)
        }
        else{
          this.item_qty -= 1;
          console.log('item_2->' + this.item_qty);
        }
      }
```

html

```
 <div class = "col-md-3 float-plus">
      <ion-buttons>
        <div *ngIf="!hideMe[displayItems.ITEMID]">

      <button ion-button outline color = "dark" (click)="addQuantity(displayItems)">
        <!-- Add &nbsp; -->
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
      </button> 
    </div> 



      <div *ngIf="hideMe[displayItems.ITEMID]">
      <div>
          <div class="outline">
                <button class="small-btn"  ion-button outline small color = "dark" (click)="subQuantity(displayItems)">
                    <!-- Add &nbsp; -->
                    <ion-icon name="remove"></ion-icon>
                  </button>
              <h5 class="count" *ngIf="val.ITEMID === displayItems.ITEMID;">
               {{item_qty}}
               </h5>
                <ng-template #nothing>
                  <!-- <strong> {{cartCount}} </strong> -->
                </ng-template>

        <button  class="small-btn" style="float: right" ion-button outline small color = "dark" (click)="addQuantity(displayItems)">
          <!-- Add &nbsp; -->
        <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>

        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>



  </ion-buttons>
</div>
```

I want the counter to increment/decrement for specific items only. I have been trying for a long time please help.

Comment: Can you share the data structure that you have for your items?

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko 
When I click the add button this is the structure I get for every specific item,
CUSTOM: []
DESC: ""
FROM: "00:00:00"
ITEMID: "6778"
ITEMNAME: "Chicken Shawarma (Bread)"
PIC: ""
RATE: "60.00"
TIME: "N"
TO: "00:00:00"
TYPE: "N"

I just want to add a count for every item and decrement for every item.

Comment: Hey sorry this is very confusing. Please share your data model inside your question. Why dont you have such counter stored in your data model per item?